# React error: "React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency"

Tags: node.js

I faced an error which is:

> React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'productId'. Either include it or remove the dependency array  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps

Comment: Questions here generally need: (a) the code that produces the error, and (b) a helpful summary in the title. I have fixed the second one, please add the first one.

Answer (score 1):

It means that you should remove the deps array (which is not good for performance) or include `productId` in the deps array of [useEffect](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html). Something like

```
useEffect(() => {
  // your code
}, [productId]);
```

By doing so, everytime `productId` is changed, your useEffect call will be called again. Or if you understand what you are doing and you don't want to call useEffect after `productId` is changed, you can disable eslint check like [here](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/6880#issuecomment-485912528).

Answer (score 0):

**Reason of error**

The reason for this error is, that we are using dependencies in the useEffect but we are not calling it in the callBack, as per react life cycle if you don't mention a dependency for React it may because it be a infinite loop, below you can see the example and solutions.

**Fault in code**

```
useEffect(() => {
  productId;
}, []);
```

**Solutions**

there are 2 methods to overcome this error

**1. Declare the variable in useEffect callback**

```
useEffect(() => {
  productId;
}, [productId]);
```

**2. Disable eslint's warning**

```
useEffect(() => {
 productId
}, []) // eslint-disable-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
```